# VS Code won't recognize Java commands (java.runtime) or run java apps

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

I have JDK 19 installed and properly configured in PATH. I setup `java.configuration.runtimes` and `java.jdt.ls.java.home` in VS Code settings.

When I try to access java commands such as Configure Java Runtime, I get an error prompt `command 'java.runtime' not found`, and attempting to run java apps within VS Code does nothing.

[error prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sISqr.png)

[vscode config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IYTRp.png)

[jdk install](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KBIP5.png)

Tried reinstalling VS Code, changing JDK versions, removing Code folder under app data, nothing works. The red hat java language support package loads and recognizes things fine. I can manually run the app from cmd using `javac` so it's just a VS Code issue with not recognizing the installed JDK it seems

Answer (score 0):

This is the command of the Java expansion package in VSCODE, which has nothing to do with your JDK installation.

Make sure to install a complete [Extension Pack for Java](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vscjava.vscode-java-pack). Or switch to the ***pre -release*** version.

[image]

[*Getting Started with Java in VS Code*](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-tutorial)

Comment: I do have the full extension pack installed, unfortunately switching to pre-release didn't fix the problem